# textarea not works on document load with value

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

The code below shows the code i have tried.

```
<textarea name="description" id="description"  cols="30" rows="5" wrap="soft"     value="${event.description}"></textarea>
```

If we try this with the input type=text gives the output.

```
<input id="description" type="text" class="datepicker" value="${event.description}">
```

Please anyone tell why its happening and how it can be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML `textarea` `won't provide value attribute`. Instead if we want to access value inside HTML area then we need to place values in between `<textarea>` start and end tag i.e.

```
<textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="5" wrap="soft">
     ${event.description}
</textarea>
```

[Refer this textarea Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. That works.I was unaware of that problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this, value for textarea must be enclosed in the tag:

```
<textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="5" wrap="soft">${event.description}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<textarea/>` doesn't have a `value` attribute. It has `textContent`, so you should do:

```
<textarea>${event.description}</textarea>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea